# Python and ANSI escape characters

Tags: python, syntax, escaping, ansi-escape

I am a month into learning the python programming language and I am using IntelliJ IDEA IDE. I cannot wrap my head around this syntax structure: \u001b

Currently learning about changing the text color, so am trying to decipher simple code like '\u001b[34m'.

If anyone chooses to graciously expand on that code in as elaborate explanation as possible that would be mahvelous!

Is \ a python escape character and then, 'u001b' is the ANSI/UTF/ASCII escape character, followed by '[34' which is the ANSI/UTF/ASCII color code, and finally closing off the command with 'm'?

If this question comes across as dense, please assist to clear my dense head, appreciate any and all input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `termcolor` library, where there is a `cprint()`(color print) function you can use to print text in colors.

Installation:

```sh
pip install termcolor
```

Usage:

```py
import sys
from termcolor import colored, cprint

text = colored('Hello, World!', 'red', attrs=['reverse', 'blink'])
print(text)
cprint('Hello, World!', 'green', 'on_red')

print_red_on_cyan = lambda x: cprint(x, 'red', 'on_cyan')
print_red_on_cyan('Hello, World!')
print_red_on_cyan('Hello, Universe!')

for i in range(10):
    cprint(i, 'magenta', end=' ')

cprint("Attention!", 'red', attrs=['bold'], file=sys.stderr)
```

Output:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl88e.png)

EDIT: The first one is actually blinking, but you don't get to see it in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

\u001b is simply an escape sequence for a Unicode character, which Python interprets in a string and replaces with it's actual value. Take a look at [this](https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html).

In addition to @timthedev07's answer, there is (in my opinion) a better library called Colorama, which simply provides static string values to concatenate with (e.g. `Back.GREEN + "Green background" + Fore.RED + "Green background and red foreground" + Back.RESET + "Reset"`).